# URL rewrite using .htaccess for file in folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have URL like `www.xyz.com/profile.php?username=test` and i want it to be like `www.xyz.com/profile/test` this is not works because i have addded htaccess code for remove folder name from url

My htaccess Code is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).*)$ pages/$1       

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/` in front of profile.php. Also quotes might help:

```
RewriteRule "^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" "/profile.php?username=$1"
```